# Excel: "Cannot Load the specified XML or schema source"

Tags: excel, xml, xsd, schema

I'm trying to convert an XML schema into an excel form for populating the data elements and exporting it as XML file. I'm using the Developer Ribbon within Excel, however, when trying to load the XML below, I get the an error saying the .xsd file cannot be opened. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Excel Error:**

[image]

**XML Schema: [Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mrdopPyCqU3HDPRU72OQZhxOrMuLW4UQ)**

Comment: What happens when you click "Details..." button?

Comment: @tomredfern it says that the system cannot find the path specified

Comment: Then that's the problem. It can't find the file. Try putting it somewhere local like C:\

Comment: @tomredfern but I'm loading it through excel using its file explore, how can it not find it?  I tried putting it in the C drive, but that did not solve it unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Issue was that the XML schema was badly formatted. Loaded the very original file and it solved the issue.